# Exceptions on c++

Tags: c++, exception, methods, overloading

I have this:

```
// exception::what
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <exception>      // std::exception


struct ooops : std::exception {
 const char* what() const noexcept {return "Ooops!\n";}
};


class A: std::exception{
  public: 
    int tt;
    int getTT(int rr){
      if (rr ==5) throw ooops();
      return rr;
    };  
};

int main () {
 try {
   A testA;
   int ww = testA.getTT("kkk");
   std::cout << ww << std::endl;//throw ooops();
 } catch (std::exception& ex) {
  std::cout << ex.what();
 }
 return 0;
}
```

I want to call `getTT()` with the string above and I want to throw My Exception message instead the default one. I know that If I overload a method from Exception class I will be ok but I am asking if there is a more easy way to do it.I am reading the documentation on Exceptions but I can't find something useful.

Comment: *"I want to call the `getTT()` with the string"* `getTT()` takes an int, not a string. *"instead the default one"* What do you mean by that? There ain't no such thing as a "default exception". You can throw an object of any type. All in all, it's unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: I honestly do not understand what you are intending to do.. Please explain what you wanr

Comment: Why `A` inherits from `std::exception`?

Answer (score 3):

You can throw any object. you don't have to inherit from `std::exception`

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
public:
    int tt;
    int getTT(int rr){
        if (rr ==5) throw "ooops";
        return rr;
    };
};

int main () {
    try {
        A testA;
        int ww = testA.getTT(5);
        std::cout << ww << std::endl;//throw ooops();
    } catch (const char* exc) {
        std::cout << exc;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And If you don't know the type of the exception, you can use `...`, as follows

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
public:
    int tt;
    int getTT(int rr){
        if (rr ==5) throw "ooops";
        return rr;
    };
};

int main () {
    try {
        A testA;
        int ww = testA.getTT(5);
        std::cout << ww << std::endl;//throw ooops();
    } catch (...) {
        std::cout << "exception has been thrown";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `ooops` class should derive from
[`std::runtime_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) instead, which takes a user-defined string as input and overrides `what()` for you to return that string.

There are other mistakes in your code, too. `A` should not derive from `std::exception`. And `A::getTT()` takes an `int` as input, but you are trying to pass it a string literal (`const char[4]`) instead.

Try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

struct ooops : std::runtime_error {    
    ooops(const std::string &what_arg = "Ooops!")
        : runtime_error(what_arg)
    {
    }
};

class A {
public:
    int tt;
    int getTT(int rr) const {
        if (rr == 5) throw ooops("rr can't be 5");
        return rr;
    }
};

int main () {
    try {
        A testA;
        int ww = testA.getTT(5);
        std::cout << ww << std::endl; // throw ooops();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```